# Strange usage of dependent clauses

Tags: grammar

Before asking my question, I would like to point out that English is not my mother tongue, and that consequently, my choice of terminology might be inappropriate.

I have noticed that in many cases, there is a very strange combination of dependent (sub?) clauses in the English language.To be more specific, consider the following quote from wikipedia's artcile on [Barack Obama](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barack_Obama):

> Born in Honolulu, Hawaii, Obama is a graduate of Columbia University and Harvard Law School, where he was president of the Harvard Law Review.

What does, apart from any weak and uncited statistical correlation there might be, the fact that Barack Obama was born in Honolulu have to with the fact that he is a graduate of Columbia and Harvard? To me this is a very bizarre way of writing a sentence, and it makes just as much sense as saying "Born in Honolulu, Obama ate an apple on the 4th of july 1990" (no idea if he actually *did*).

Has anybody else noticed this absurdity? Does anybody have an explanation for it? Is it merely a failed attempt at giving the text a good "flow"?

Comment: All statements provide background on the individual.  It does not strike me as *absurd.*

Comment: @Lumberjack: Yes, it is true that all statements provide background on the individual. But I still think they are not very strongly connected to each other, so it seems strange to me that some of them should be subclauses.

Comment: This is newspaperese. The copywriter had a lot of facts to get in and wanted to vary his presentation. What he wrote is arguably better than this litany of declaratives: "Obama is a graduate of Columbia University and Harvard Law School. He was president of the Harvard Law Review. He was born in Honolulu, Hawaii."

Comment: @Robusto: As I tried to indicate by my last question, I also suspect this is the case. Still, I don't think it makes sense.

Comment: A: I don't follow your posts, so I have no idea what you tried to indicate in your last question. B: It sure does make sense. C: Trying to find a way to convince you, I am now using the same construction in what may be thought of as "perfect" (or at least perfectly acceptable) English.

Comment: @Robusto: A: I have only made one post. I meant the last sentence of this post, " Is it merely a failed attempt at giving the text a good "flow"? ", that happened to be a question. C: I don't think your example is of the same sort as the one I provided. The first clause of your sentence doesn't provide information irrelevant to the following sub clauses.

Comment: Relevance is in the eye of the beholder. You may argue that the facts are not of equal weight, but such a discussion does not really fall under the category of what we do here.

Comment: @Robusto: Alright, I guess I am not going to get any further with this here in the comment section. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Most anglophones would not bat an eyelid at your first sentence – potted histories, necessarily disjoint, are usually considered to be cohesive enough not to jar. However, the 'apple' sentence contains bathos, which is a different matter.

Comment: Where, Who, What, ... in that order, in one sentence, grammatical and unambiguous, newsy. Actually, a text-book one-sentence bio from birth to present.

Comment: Thanks for your input! While I do understand your arguments, it still sounds strange to me.

Answer (score 1):

If I may chime in belatedly in support of Robusto's first comment above, the posted example is simply an instance of newspaperese.

Journalists (and other writers) are trained to avoid composing series of simple declarative sentences because, all too often, the resulting prose sounds wooden:

> Obama was born in Honolulu, Hawaii.
>
> Obama is a graduate of Columbia University and Harvard Law School.
>
> Obama was president of the Harvard Law Review.

But when a ham-handed writer attempts to combine a series of loosely related (or utterly unrelated) details, the result can be off-putting to readers who expect to see some causal (or at least transitional) connection between the various details that appear in the same sentence.

Thus, for example, a scattershot reporter might turn in a sentence like this:

> Left-handed, Obama attended Occidental College in Eagle Rock, California, two decades before achieving passage of an ambitious but controversial federal healthcare law.

Like the OP's example, this sentence passes muster grammatically, and it isn't boring in the "Obama is... Obama was... Obama was..." way that the details might be if presented as a series simple sentences. But at some point, the unrelatedness of the points that the writer puts in such close proximity begins to wear on readers, who expect to find some closer relation among the details than the fact that they all refer to the same person.

To the extent that readers infer that Obama's left-handedness, matriculation at Occidental College, and championing of the federal healthcare law are mentioned together because they are related in some unstated way, readers are allowing their expectation of the details' relevance to each other in the sentence to lead them astray. To a lesser extent, the same issue arises in connection with the OP's example.

My advice is to read defensively: Try not to assume that a causal relationship exists between details that merely happen to appear contiguously. Skillful writers don't habitually assemble such potentially misleading amalgams, but everyone makes mistakes—and many writers simply aren't very skillful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the statement implies that being born in Honolulu has anything to do with the second part of the statement. It is just a contracted way of writing the following sentence with the relative clause being replaced by a participle clause. It is very common to do so.

Obama, *who was born in Honolulu, Hawaii,* is a graduate of Columbia University and Harvard Law School, where he was president of the Harvard Law Review.

The above sentence is just stating an additional fact about Obama, that has no bearing whatsoever on the rest of the sentence.
The relative clause can be replaced by a participle clause starting with *born*
eg: Obama, *born in Honolulu...*
And the position of the phrase can be changed without changing the meaning.

That said there are uses of the participle to signify consequence or reason where they replace *since, because* etc, but that is just one of the uses of it.

http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/grammar-reference/participle-clauses

Answer (score -1):

I'm American and yes, that is very strange. Wikipedia can be edited by anyone so it is most likely the work of someone under educated.

Comment: You're entitled to your opinion, but please forgive me if I don't want your opinion to represent us all.  I too am American, and it is not in any way strange to me.

Comment: @user55789: I wouldn't be so certain it is done by someone undereducated, but it is nice to know that someone here agrees with me :)